# Why do Entity Framework entity sets have name of "it"?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging, entity-framework

I am debugging some Entity Framework code in Visual Studio 2008, and I'm trying to retrieve actual values from the database. I expect to see a set of ID, Name pairs from one static table.

```
using (MyModel context = new MyModel())
{
    var stat = context.StatusSet.First(x => x.ID == 1);
    //...
}
```

When I look into context I instead see that context.StatusSet.Name has the value of "it".

What does this mean?

Comment: Purely speculative, but it sounds like a "root" node in the object hierarchy, with a name reminiscent of *"this"*.

Comment: i don't know, but in EF1 i have seen some code in linq to entities where a colleague had to do a sort of where statement, and it also contained the 'magic string' 'IT'

Comment: @Michel: I've seen examples of such where statements. Perhaps that the approach I need to take, as this expression isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL variants like T-SQL, there is an implicit this object, so you only need to specify the column names. However, you can specify an alias for a table (e.g., SELECT a.* FROM Table a).

The Entity Framework has the ability to run queries using ESQL (or Entity SQL), which is a SQL based langauge. In ESQL, there isn't an implicit this scope, you need to explicitly use "it" to refer to the current scope.

Erick

Comment: I have been trying to find out more about "it". Even the ADO.NET Team blogs don't seem to cover this.

Comment: Agreed, it is not a well covered aspect of eSQL, even in the MSDN documentation.